# WSDL with minoccurs="0", data not sent

Tags: java, c#, wcf, wsdl, svcutil.exe

We have two services.

One is written in `Java` and hosted in a `glassfish`, 
the other written as a `WCF service library` in `C#` and hosted in `IIS`.

When I want to communicate with the `Java service`, I use the `wsdl`, generate a proxy via `svcutil` and want to send data.

There are some enum values specified in that `wsdl`, which have `minoccurs="0"` set.

If I call an method on that proxy with an object that contains such enums, they do not get sent.

I turned on tracing as described in [How to: configure network tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and turned all of the tracing as described in [Configuring tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So I see the envelope and there is no value for the enum. There is not even an attribute set, this part is completely missing.

Can I handle this somehow in proxy-generation with `svcutil`? 
If the `minoccurs` is deleted from the `wsdl`, everything works fine.

I have checked the generated proxy and to not see any difference there regarding the class / enum elements generated.

Answer (score 1):

If the WSDL for your java service is such that SVCUTIL generates XmlSerializer-based contracts, then you have to make sure that you set the right fields on the contract object before sending the data.

In such a case you should have another boolean field/property on the contract named Specified, you need to set it to true to tell the XmlSerializer that the  contains a non-null value.

Comment: Good point, but right now I do not see such a field. The XML Serializer is chosen.

Comment: What does your WSDL look like?